# Undefined function or variable 'mmread' - Matlab

Tags: matlab, video

Im trying to write a code in Matlab that uses the function "mmread".

At first I got the following error:

```
 "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32"
```

I searched the web and found that I hade to download mmread and located it in "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32", so I did. But still it doesn't work.

When I try to run it on the command window, like that:

```
  mmread('C:\videosFolder\video1.avi');
```

I get the following warning:

```
  Warning: In the directory "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win32\mmread", mexDDGrab.mexw32 now shadows mexDDGrab.dll.
```

Please see the MATLAB 7.1 Release Notes.

And when I try to run my code:

```
  [~,audio]=mmread(pathname,[],[n n+1],true,false,'',true,false);
```

I get the followinf error:

```
  Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

Any suggestions ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The error contains no further information?? This may seem a silly question but has this directory been added to your matlab path.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. And Yes I Added it to the matlab path. Anyway, I editted the Question. Please read it again.

Comment: What version of matlab are you using? Using `~` as an output argument was added fairly recently and causes problems on versions of matlab that don't support it.

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh: I cant seem to find `mmread`, did you mean [`mmreader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mmreaderclass.html)?

Comment: @slayton: I'm using matlab 2008. Does it support it?

Comment: @Amro: No I meant mmread. there is a different between the two functions. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh No, suppression of function outputs using `~` was introduced within the last year or two. I suspect that is a causing the parsing error

Comment: I just tested it, 2010a does the ~ but 2009a does not, so with 2008 you would have to use [temp,audio]=mmread() ingoring the content of temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it, 2010a does the ~ but 2009a does not, so with 2008 you would have to use [temp,audio]=mmread() ingoring the content of temp